# Open Modal via php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Have the simple code (see below) on one of my pages, after the guest have login they are return back to the main page were they should be meet with a little pop-up modal with a thank you message. 
Have tried multiply variation on this but none work, this should be a simnple as ABC put it's not working?.

```
 <?php if(isset($thx) === 'Y'){?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $('#\\#thx').modal('show');
       </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Define "none work". What happens? Errors? invalid results?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: `if(isset($thx) === 'Y')` is wrong. `isset()` returns a boolean. A boolean will never be identical to 'Y'

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the JQuery script in document ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#\\#thx').modal('show');
});
```

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     //your code here   
 })
```

This will run your function when page load.

Comment: Add your modal html to the question please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php if(isset($thx) == "Y"){?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).on('ready',function({
             $('#thx').modal('show', true);
         });
       </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Had not tried it with the second parameter (true), but have now tried but still no modal, thanks

Comment: @PeterBaker: Is it a bootstrap modal? Have you included "bootstrap" and "jquery" (.js and .css) in your code? Also try to inspect your result: Preferably in Chrome, right-click on your page and choose inspect. In the inspection window select the "Console" tab, and look in there for any errors (in red color) that may occur during the load of your page. Also try to create an element to fire the modal manually (to ensure that it works).

Comment: Already inspected via the console log comes up clear.. It's a real head scratcher, Think I will just rip  it out and drop in an alter

Comment: Have you tried to create an element to fire the modal manually (on click)?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to be here:

`if(isset($thx) === 'Y')`

`isset()` will return a boolean. That is to say `true` or `false`.
You are then comparing `true` or `false` with `'Y'` but asking if they are identical.

An identical check `===` means that they need to be both the same type and the same value. As a boolean is not a string, they are not the same type, so the test will fail.

For more information, see the php manual for [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

---

You probably want something like the following:

`if(isset($thx) && $thx === 'Y')`